# differences between dtexec.exe and dtexecui.exe(Execute Package Utility)

Tags: oracle, ssis, package, execute, drivers

I would love to know the differences between **dtexec.exe** and **dtexecui.exe**(Execute Package Utility)
example a few things that i know is that,

1. dtexecui.exe is a 32 bit application, while dtexec.exe has 32 and 64 version.

I would love to know if there are other differences that exist between those two.
Things like,

- do they run packages differently?,
- do they have preferences on which oracle client they will use to connect to the databases, if you have both 32 and 64 bit clients?,
- or any other differences
- Which oracle drivers do each of those use to connect to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Both dtexec.exe and dtexecui.exe execute SSIS packages in the same manner. The difference is that dtexecui provided a graphical user interface to construct the command line arguments for dtexec. The command string that is generated with dtexecui can be used as command line arguments to dtexec.

Since they execute in the same manner there is no distinction between which clients they will use. The clients and drivers are determined by the package or by the command line parameters for each package executed.

For information on executing packages using dtexecui please see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141707(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. I can run .dstx packages I created with the DTSWizard.exe from DTExecUI.exe but they will not run from DTExec.exe, claiming "Data Flow objects can not be loaded". I've been searching for a solution, but so far have come up short.